# Are echhi anime haram?

Tags: halal-haram, image, cartoon

Echhi anime involve nudity such as Breasts and nipples being shown but never the vagina or any sex in it. Since there is no sex in it like porn is it haram. Echhi anime kind of control your desires so are ecchi anime ok??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the holy quoran states (i can't remember the exact verse at the moment) that all our senses are held responsible (i.e. eyes, ears, intellect, ... even our feelings). so watching haram scenes with the intention of not pursuing the issue physically, is not only "absolutely and obviously haraam", its also impractical as well. and unethical.

also to mention, pornography has different levels and types of approach. sadly.

Answer (score 1):

regardless of what you're watching, if something other than your wife is controlling your sexual desires, it must be refrained from as shaitaan is trying to make you have more of it. if you really want to watch anime, watch the good ones like Naruto, Dragon Ball Z, Attack on titans, death note or akame ga kill. these anime are just normal cartoon you can watch and don't tempt you to do anything which keeps you away from the bad kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

Yes, firstly because it shows the drawn 'awrah (islamically considered private parts of a human) of women which come under the same ruling as seeing real private parts of women **if** the drawing is realistic, and anime is one of the most realistic ways of drawing, and realistic here means realistic in the sense of the drawing having realistic bodily and facial features and resembling the creation of Allah, and to explain the 'awrah parts of women:

> “*And tell the believing women to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts) and not to show off their adornment except only that which is apparent (like both eyes for necessity to see the way, or outer palms of hands or one eye or dress like veil, gloves, headcover, apron), and to draw their veils all over Juyoobihinna (i.e. their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms)…*” *(Quran source)* https://islamqa.info/en/21134
>   [al-Noor 24:31]

so from this we understand that all of the parts of the woman are awrah when she is with a non-mahram(s) (.i.e the ones who are not haram for her to marry) except the nasalis, orbicular oculis, the eyes, and what is horizontally around it until the all the way until the orbicular oculis (horizontally) .i.e what is around the eyes horizontally. End quote.

secondly: the whole category of Ecchi is based mainly on immorality so yes, animes of the ecchi category are completely haram, because the plot revolves greatly around immorality if not only.

thirdly: you mentioned that it shows some of the private parts of the woman, which is tempting, and may lead to the major sin of masturbating, which is forbidden because Allah says in the Quran:

> "And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts, from illegal sexual acts). Except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors." 23:5-7 *(Quran source)* https://islamqa.info/en/329

so since the only acceptable way for a man or woman to satisfy their sexual desires and needs is to do it with their spouses or and **man** to do it with what his right hands possesses (the captives and slaves) we understand that masturbation is a big and forbidden sin in islam, End quote.